# Two routing strings are appending to one another in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In the code below `location_id = "Roger"` and `court_id = "court1"`

```
return webapp2.redirect("/schedule/%s/%s" % (location_id, court_id))
```

Where the get definition is as follows

```
class Schedule(BaseHandler):
    def get(self, location_id, court_id):
        self.render_template('schedule.html', {'location':location_id,'court':court_id})
```

But when I reach the schedule.html template using the following routing,

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/', MainPage), 
        ('/create/([\w]+)', CreateCourt), 
        ('/createlocation/([\w]+)', CreateLocation), 
        ('/schedule/([\w]+/([\w]+))', Schedule) 
        ],
        debug=True)
```

The value of `location` has grown to include a `/` and the value of `court`: "Roger/court1".

How can I keep the two parts of "location/court" separate?
I suspect the answer has to do with the routing regexp for /schedule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're right - in your `schedule` handler, it looks like you're missing the closing parenthesis (never typed that singular before - weird :) ). Try this:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/', MainPage), 
        ('/create/([\w]+)', CreateCourt), 
        ('/createlocation/([\w]+)', CreateLocation), 
        ('/schedule/([\w]+)/([\w]+)', Schedule) 
        ],
        debug=True)
```

Comment: Yes, that's the problem all right. Even you got the correction wrong with an extra ')'. <grin> But you got the important part right. `('/schedule/([\w]+)/([\w]+)', Schedule)` Thanks.

Comment: Haha, corrected (regex always makes my head spin). Glad it works.